# State machine to handle sequential and async events

Tags: objective-c, enums, state, state-machine

I created this `state machine` to handle events. I'm unsure about my implementation **firstly** because I don't use a transition table or anything like that, instead, I simply input the next event/state that needs to happen. I think this is cleaner than calling method to handle `event b` inside the method to handle `event a`, right?

**Secondarily**, since some of the methods have parameters - and this is not `swift` where enum members can have associated values, I added a param for that via `withObj` argument. I don't see a problem with this but want to know if this is confusing/violating something from your perspective.

**I also found this useful for async task**, so after the task completes I set resulting value to a local variable then update state to `packData` using that stored value amongst many other values already existing. This value is packed in a byte array which cannot be used in blocks so this was a useful workaround - although I haven't tested yet.

States are defined via `enum` like so:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ExampleState) {
    ExampleStateIdle,
    ExampleStateWaitingForAsyncTask,
    ExampleStateReadyToPack,
    ExampleStateRespond,
    ExampleStateSomethingInProgress,
    ExampleStateSomething2InProgress,
    ExampleStateComplete
};
```

Here I define a method to handle each event using helper methods. **I also have an extra argument for any state that might have an `associated value`**.

```
- (void)updateState:(ExampleState)state withObj:(id)obj  {

    self.currentState = state;

    switch (state) {
        case ExampleStateWaitingForAsyncTask:
            [self getAsyncInfo];
            break;
        case ExampleStateReadyToPack:
            [self packData];
            break;
        case ExampleStateRespond:
            [self respond:obj];
            break;
        case ExampleStateComplete:
            [self showPopup];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
-(void)packData {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&result length:resultIndex];
    // next step is to respond to `client`/`central` with data
    [self updateState:ExampleStateRespond withObj:data];
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Willeke Is this a clean and proper implementation of a state machine? Although my use case is quite simple, other implementations were more complex and abstract.

Comment: See [Where can I post code for others to review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90362/where-can-i-post-code-for-others-to-review)